# How can i add pagination to my dynamic table which is developed in javascript?

Tags: javascript, pagination

How can i add pagination to my dynamic table which is developed in javascript?

```
function printing_numbers(sum){


    elements =  document.getElementById('OMG3').innerHTML= "";
    if(sum==0){document.getElementById('OMG3').innerHTML= "";}


    if(sum>5){

            for(i=1; i<= sum; i++){

                elements =  
                document.getElementById('OMG3').innerHTML += '<button type="button" onclick="myfun('+i+','+sum+')" id='+i+' style=" margin:1px auto; float:left; padding:5px 5px;" class="inactive">'+i+'</button>';
               document.getElementById('OMG3').style.cssFloat +="left";
               document.getElementById('OMG3').style.border +="0";
               document.getElementById('OMG3').style.backgroundColor +="none"; 
                       }

     }else if(sum > 1){
            for(i=1; i<= sum; i++){
               elements =  

               document.getElementById('OMG3').innerHTML += '<button type="button" onclick="myfun('+i+','+sum+')" id='+i+' style=" margin:1px auto; float:left; padding:5px 5px;" class="inactive">'+i+'</button>';
               document.getElementById('OMG3').style.cssFloat +="left"; 
               document.getElementById('OMG3').style.border +="0";
               document.getElementById('OMG3').style.backgroundColor +="none";

            }

    }
}
```

Comment: Does any of the answers solve your problem? If so, please select the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this free library for jQuery which will do everything you want and more:
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multi_col_sort.html

It works by talking a normal HTML table from the DOM and then turning it into a dynamic table.

you can also add your won styling to to it to make it fit into your site, here is a Bootstrap 3 implementation: https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html

(Sorry for only supplying links, this would be a bit long for a comment)

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to display only a subset of the content at a time. This means that you need to have the current *page* number and *amount* of data displayed stored somewhere (for example in the URL as a parameter).

For example in pseudo code

```
//let's say that you have your result array stored in the variable "results"
var page = 1; //first page
var amount = 20; //the amount of results to be shown
```

now when you display the results do

```
for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++){
    if(i < page*amount && i <= page*amount - amount){
        resultsToShow.push(results[i]);
    }
}
showResults(resultsToShow);
```

For the pagination button you just need to increase or decrease the `page` variable.